# Possible to created a submenu programmatically in c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

On my page theres buttons on the top. I would like to add sub menus to those buttons:

```
protected void AddMenuItems()
{
    // Check privledges and add links to admin pages accordingly.
    // List adds pages in order of user precedence.


    if (_cu.IsUser)
    {
       NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Generate UserIDs", "Generate UserIDs", null, "~/GenPrefixList.aspx"));
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can add a sub menu to the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each `MenuItem` has a `ChildItems` collection to which you can add an indefinite number of items.

```
protected void AddMenuItems()
{
    // Check privledges and add links to admin pages accordingly.
    // List adds pages in order of user precedence.


    if (_cu.IsUser)
    {
       var newItem = new MenuItem("Generate UserIDs", "Generate UserIDs", null, "~/GenPrefixList.aspx");
       var subItem = new MenuItem("Sub Menu Item", "Submenu Item", null, "page.aspx");
       newItem.ChildItems.Add(subItem);
       NavigationMenu.ChildItems.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

The "Sub Menu Item" will be a child of "Geneate UserIDs", which is a child of the navigation menu.

**Update**: The `Items` reference in your code should be `ChildItems`. `Items` is the collection used for the Windows application menu; you added the ASP.NET tag so I assume this is a web application.

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItem' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: ...are you doing this in the forms designer or ASP.NET? If ASP.NET, then remove the `System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem` reference. I copied your code, but the `Items` should be `ChildItems` in that case.